# Why doesn't a form immediately call its submission handler?

Tags: forms

I have a form which is called from a page function. The page initially makes some external calls to get #default_value data which gets passed to `drupal_get_form()`. When the form is submitted, the page function gets called before the submission handler. Why is that? I don't get it and I don't want that to happen because it then connects to an external data API for no reason.

Does anyone know of a good place to find the calls order for a default submission handler? I'm unable to debug this.

There is an AJAX update when the form inputs refresh, but I don't see how that matters.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($form['#submit'])` from `hook_form_alter`? There may be some information in there. You can `array_unshift($form['submit'],'my_custom_callback_function')` to place your callback first in the callstack. Is that at all what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this, we should step back a bit in look at how forms are used regardless of what CMS (if any) is in use.

All `<form>` tags have an `action` attribute which define what page the browser should send the data to. If `action` is left blank (or missing) the browser will assume it should send the data to the same URL it is currently on. In this scenario the URL will be loaded to get the form *and* then again to send the data.

This is how the Form API works (by default). When you define a URL (using `hook_menu` I presume) that presents a form to the user, the browser will use the same URL to load and send the form.

The menu router in Drupal has to be run first so it can determine what page to display. Only after that does Drupal see that it has a form and then run the submit callback. **In other words, you cannot change the order of these functions.**

You can provide an [#action](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#action) attribute in your Form API implementation which (combined with a new `hook_menu` entry) should let you separate your form load/submit functions.

Comment: Note that providing a custom #action callback means that you loose all the built-in (security) features of the Form API, e.g. CRSF protection. You really shouldn't do this. Instead, you could for example cache the data from the external service using the cache API().

Comment: you guys are awesome thanks! it seems like a silly question now. Cache api looks simple too.